# Yii tstranslate widget categories

Tags: yii

I am using tstranslate-widget for a multi language website from [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/tstranslation).

By far it is a very good extension, but I am having trouble showing the categories like (site/category,site/login etc) of the web when clicking translate. What else am I supposed to do except those mentioned in the documentation?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not", please give your question a meaningful title!

Answer (score 0):

just add

```
<?php echo Yii::t(null, '<p>Congratulations! You have successfully created your Yii application.</p>');?>
```

to the index.php and I think it will show (site / index)